# Notificaciones Push en Android con Firebase utilizando el token

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Buen día espero que se comprenda la pregunta, como ven estoy tratando de mandar una notificación a un usuario en especifico dependiendo de una acción, me explico:

Tengo una aplicación de pedidos la cual el usuario realiza su pedido luego ese pedido llega al administrador, el administrador puede finalizar el pedido cuando este listo una vez hecho esto el cliente recibe la notificación de que su pedido ya esta finalizado y ya lo puede pasar a recoger, entonces aquí es donde radica el problema he estado leyendo mucha documentación y he visto muchos videos pero veo que para enviar una notificación a un usuario en especifico entran a la consola de `Firebase` y ponen el token del usuario en la configuración y proceden a enviar el mensaje, entonces para lo que yo necesito no es lo correcto obviamente ya que tengo que enviar la notificación de manera automática cuando el administrador finalice el pedido, he encontrado una implementación donde la notificación se envía a todos los usuarios que tengan la aplicación instalada y he tratada de adaptarla para que envié a un solo usuario utilizando su token, ahora voy a proceder a mostrar lo que tengo hasta el momento:

Lo primero que hago es obtener el `token` del usuario:

```
private void obtenerToken() {

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.w("TAG", "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
                return;
            }

            // Get new FCM registration token
            String token = task.getResult();

            // Log and toast
            String msg = "El token es el siguiente:" + token;
            Log.d("TAG", msg);
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Este código lo tengo en mi clase principal para que de entrada se obtenga dicho token, luego pienso almacenarlo en mi base de datos `MySQL` y cada vez que el usuario se "logee" ese token se este actualizando en mi base de datos por si en alguna ocasión el usuario borra datos, desinstala, etc...

Luego el administrador entra con sus privilegios a la aplicación cuando hay pedidos nuevos para esto he creado un `Recyclerview` donde obtengo los pedidos desde `MySQL` usando `PHP`

Dentro de mi clase adaptador tengo mi clase `llamarTopico()` donde personalizo mi mensaje

```
RequestQueue myrequest= Volley.newRequestQueue(cContext);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {

        String url_foto="";

        json.put("to","/topics/"+"enviaratodos");
        JSONObject notificacion=new JSONObject();
        notificacion.put("titulo", "Tu pedido ya esta listo");
        notificacion.put("detalle","¡Ya puedes recoger tu pedido en el restaurante");
        notificacion.put("foto",url_foto);

        json.put("data",notificacion);
        String URL="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null,null){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String,String>header=new HashMap<>();
                header.put("content-type","application/json");
                header.put("authorization","key=AAAA4_Ez5Uc:APA91bGikOqTotdNVNpNsCKX3g5f0582UT1JKGFlgumT0NvHKydOC8aVxU7B6PGh0GIhHW-N_rDhVSnyGtuyDQSL1J_xDR8rKbJG2899OGA_I1RUE0oRlM5fvmoY0v84KjWxCkoCwgUb");
                
                return header;

            }
        };
        myrequest.add(request);


    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

En esta parte hay 3 cosas que aclarar:

**1)** Cuando el usuario finaliza el pedido se ejecuta el método claro en mi base de datos el pedido ya se ha actualizado a finalizado por ende no existiría ningún problema al momento de enviar la notificación en el hipotético caso que el código funcionara como lo necesito.

**2)** Yo pensaba que si cambiaba el **key** de la linea `header.put("authorization","key=` por mi token el mensaje se enviaría justamente al dispositivo de ese token pero por lo visto no es así y mi token lo tengo que usar en otro lugar esa **key** que acabo de mencionar es la clave del servidor que obtengo de firebase.

**3)** He descubierto que puedo pasar el token como parámetro en esta linea `json.put("to","/topics/"+"enviaratodos");`  por lo tanto he tratado de crear una variable String token = "mi token"; y pasarla como parámetro en el `json` `json.put("to","/topics/"+token);` sin embargo no envía la notificación

Algo que vale la pena agregar es que según la implementación de la que me guie se crea este método:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(cContext,"Registrado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Si se dan cuenta el parametro que se le pasa a `subscribeTopic()` es el string que tiene el parametro del json `json.put("to","/topics/"+"enviaratodos");`

Por ultimo tengo mi claro FMC que para ser sinceros y debido a que soy nuevo en el tema no he terminado de comprender su funcionalidad:

```
public class Fcm extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("token","mi token es:"+s);

}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String from =remoteMessage.getFrom();

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
       String titulo=remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo");

        String detalle=remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle");
        String foto=remoteMessage.getData().get("foto");

            mayorqueoreo(titulo,detalle,foto);

    }
}

private void mayorqueoreo(String titulo, String detalle, String foto) {
    String id="mensaje";
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,id);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel nc=new NotificationChannel(id,"nuevo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        nc.setShowBadge(true);
        assert nm!=null;
        nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
    }
    try {

        Bitmap imf_foto= Picasso.get().load(foto).get();
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logotaqueria)

                .setContentText(detalle)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(imf_foto).bigLargeIcon(null))
                .setContentIntent(clicknoti())

                .setContentInfo("nuevo");

        Random random=new Random();
        int idNotity =random.nextInt(8000);

        assert nm !=null;
        nm.notify(idNotity,builder.build());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
public PendingIntent clicknoti(){
    Intent nf=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ObtenerReportes.class);
    nf.putExtra("color","rojo");
    nf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,nf,0);
}
```

}

Pero esta es la clase que usamos es el `Manifest` de la siguiente manera:

```
<service
        android:name=".Fcm"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

He actualizado mi pregunta según nuevas investigaciones y nuevo código que he encontrado!

Y pues creo que eso seria todo es un poco exhaustivo el código pero creo que es necesario espero que se comprenda todo si tienen alguna duda o necesitan mas código por favor hacérmelo saber al igual agradezco si alguien mejora la pregunta actualizándola de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Muy importante @AdielMoran, primero probar si recibes algo en onMessageReceived() , puedes poner un mensaje que imprima en el Log y que asegure se esta llamando el método!

Comment: Hola @Elenasys gracias por la observación en el caso de querer imprimir algo que deberia de meter el el log? porque estoy imprimiendo el from de la siguiente manera System.out.println("Mensaje recibido:" + from); si envio el mensaje a todo me imprime esto: Mensaje recibido:/topics/enviaratodos pero si utilizo el token no me muestra nada.

Comment: @Adiel Moran una observación estas enviando un push a un usuario en concreto. Piensa que un mismo usuario puede tener mas de un dispositivo y cada dispositivo con un token diferente. Tienes que tener token por dispositivo no por usuario.

Comment: Hola @JordiTurell gracias por la observación, si lo que me comentas es correcto por eso he mencionado en la pregunta que el token del usuario se actualiza en la base de datos cada vez que entra a la aplicación, por esa razón es que estoy validando por usuario y no por dispositivo!

Comment: Hola @AdielMoran he visto que tienes varios detalles incluso en la petición voy a actualizar la respuesta!

Comment: Hola @Elenasys si es que es un tema nuevo para mi por eso los detalles, gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Hola @AdielMoran he regresado, estube un poco ocupado, veo que marcaste una respuesta aceptada, pero esta es incorrecta, no vas a realizar una implementación de notificaciones para un solo usuario, esto es incorrecto, se debe realizar para todos los usuarios suscritos a un topic o tema en este caso "enviaratodos", he agreado la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuviste cerca cuando intentaste `json.put("to","/topics/"+token);`. La forma correcta de enviar la notification al usuario es pasando el token de esta manera: `json.put("to",token);`

Ahora, un poco de información adicional:

1. Espero que el código para enviar la notificación esté en tu servidor porque si el código está en la app, tu clave del servidor de Firebase estaría expuesta, así que ten en cuenta las consideraciones de seguridad. Un atacante podría personificarte y enviar notificaciones a tus usuarios.
2. La API que estás usando para enviar las notificaciones es una versión antigua y es recomendado que consideres migrar a la nueva version: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1
3. Para lo que estás tratando de hacer, no necesitas suscribir al usuario a un topic. Un topic es un mecanismo util para agrupar usuarios y enviarles notificaciones. Por ejemplo, en una tienda en linea, si usuarios desea saber cuando se lanzó un nuevo producto, puedes subscribir a esos usuarios al topic "new-products", de esta manera puedes enviar notificaciones de nuevos productos a los usuarios que estén realmente interesados, sin molestar a los demás.

Comment: Hola Julián, es increíble que solo haya tenido ese pequeño detalle, comentarte que me ha funcionado muy bien el cambio realmente te agradezco mucho, si tomare en cuenta las observaciones que mencionas debido a que soy nuevo en el tema no conozco muy bien como va esto de las notificaciones, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> si envio el mensaje a todo me imprime esto: Mensaje
> recibido:/topics/enviaratodos pero si utilizo el token no me muestra
> nada

El problema es que si registras el usuario obtienes un token pero este token debe ser generado al usar en este caso el topic "enviaratodos" !

Para asegurar que te suscribas correctamente al tema (topic) puedes usar la validaciòn de `Task` :

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos")
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {                   

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    //*Realizado satisfactoriamente.
                }else{
                    //*Error al suscribirte!
                }

             }
        });
```

Primeramente asegura lo anterior ya que probablemente el problema es al realizar la suscripciòn.

Ahora para enviar la notificación tu código es correcto, vas a enviar la notificacion a todos los usuarios que se encuentren suscrito a el topic "enviaratodos" :

```
  private void sendNotification(Context context){
        Log.i(TAG, "sendNotification() :-)");
        RequestQueue myrequest= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {

            String url_foto="https://scontent-gua1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/252413731_447363656810717_3874714756525223403_n.jpg?_nc_cat=110&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=8bfeb9&_nc_ohc=xnaYzjbprH8AX-b2HXl&_nc_ht=scontent-gua1-1.xx&oh=39529147a191bc9c14d3272548b1a9ee&oe=61ACC277";

            json.put("to","/topics/"+"enviaratodos");
            JSONObject notificacion=new JSONObject();
            notificacion.put("titulo", "Tu pedido ya esta listo");
            notificacion.put("detalle","¡Ya puedes recoger tu pedido en el restaurante");
            notificacion.put("foto",url_foto);

            json.put("data",notificacion);
            String URL="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
            JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null,null){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                    Map<String,String>header=new HashMap<>();
                    header.put("Content-Type","application/json");
                    header.put("Authorization","key=" +SERVER_AUTHORIZATION_KEY);
                    return header;
                }
            };
            myrequest.add(request);


        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

**Puedes enviar notificaciòn a un usuario usando su token**,

```
json.put("to", TOKEN_USUARIO);
```

**En el caso de enviar una notificacion los usuarios suscritos a un topic, lo que debes realizar es registrar el usuario con el `topic`** de esta forma

```
   FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos");
```

de esta forma llegará  la notificación a todos los usuarios suscritos, este sería el código completo de tu método

```
private void obtenerToken() {

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("enviaratodos");

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                Log.w("TAG", "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
                return;
            }else{
            // Get new FCM registration token
            String token = task.getResult();
            // Log and toast
            String msg = "El token es el siguiente: " + token;
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Elena, gracias por tu respuesta. Según lo que comentas pues la suscripción siempre se realiza correctamente, ahora veo que mencionas que tengo que generar el token al usar el topic? entonces debo crear el método para generar el token dentro de " if (task.isSuccessful()) { obtenerToken() } " ?

Comment: Exacto, asegura que entra aquí   if (task.isSuccessful()) {...

Comment: Como te había mencionado efectivamente entra al if y ahí estoy obteniendo el token entonces la verdadera pregunta es donde utilizo el token obtenido? en un principio suponía que lo debía usar en  json.put("to","/topics/"+"enviaratodos"); y remplazar el string "enviaratodos" por mi token pero veo que no es asi?

Comment: He encontrado el problema, he editado la respuesta para que envies la notificación a los usuarios con el topic enviaratodos

Comment: Hola Jorge, gracias por la respuesta comentarte que a pesar de que al igual que la primer respuesta esta también me ha funcionado, pero tengo una duda, según lo que comentas: "veo que marcaste una respuesta aceptada, pero esta es incorrecta, no vas a realizar una implementación de notificaciones para un solo usuario, esto es incorrecto" porque razón es incorrecto a pesar de ser lo que necesito?, por cierto he editado la respuesta eliminando la segunda imagen, fue error mio dejar la URL de una de las imagenes de la empresa, saludos.

Comment: De  acuerdo a tu còdigo inicial se supone enviarias a el topic "enviaratodos", pero en mi respuesta tambièn indico si deseas enviar a un solo usuario. Si vas a enviar un mensaje de una promociòn no lo vas a enviar a un usuario, se envìa a los usuarios que se suscribieron a dicho canal.