# Firebase Push Notifications no funciona en producción

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Buen día, tengo un problema con las notificaciones push, hace poco implemente un método de envió de notificaciones y pues todo ha funcionado muy bien en desarrollo pero al momento de subir la versión a la play store dejo de funcionar empezando por que no me obtenía el token de entrada luego trate de agregar el token manualmente y no enviaba la notificación, mi implementación es sencilla, pueden revisar mi pregunta en la cual tenia un problema para que vean el trabajo que he realizado así ya no hago tan larga esta pregunta!... esta es la pregunta que hice anteriormente:

[Notificaciones Push en Android con Firebase utilizando el token](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/495405/114296)

Bueno partiendo de esto he buscado información en muchos lugares y lo mejor que he encontrado es que debo agregar las claves sha-1 y sha-256 pero esta vez de la `Google Play Console` en el apartado "integridad de la app" sin embargo no me ha funcionado, que mas debo hacer? hay algo que estoy olvidando?

Ya he realizado estos pasos:
Ya obtuve mi sha 1 desde Android

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También fui a traer el sha 1 desde google play console

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo los agregue en firebase junto con su sha-256 (aparecen mas porque agregue unos de prueba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo no funcionan el nombre del paquete es el mismo, el json que debo agregar a Android también funciona sin embargo parece que en producción hay algo que se esta haciendo mal?

Hice una prueba obteniendo el token del dispositivo de entrada en la pantalla de inicio usando el siguiente código:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(Login.this, instanceIdResult -> {
        token = instanceIdResult.getToken();
        Log.i("FCM Token", token);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El token es "+token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
```

Como ven tengo un toast que me muestra el token pero ni siquiera entra al toast por lo que llegue a la conclusión que ya no se trata de esta implementación de notificaciones si no que cualquier servicio que utilice en firebase no funciona también hice la prueba con **SMS verification** y tampoco funciona...

Algo que cabe mencionar es que no se si **google cloud platform** tiene algo que ver con todo esto? revisando la consola de google cloud platform me doy cuenta que tiene la opcion de activar la API de notificaciones pero a pesar de que la he activando tampoco funciona ni siera se como es que la Google Cloud Platform tiene conexion con firebase pero tambien es otra posible solucion al problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y eso seria todo sinceramente debido a mi poco conocimiento no tengo ni la menor idea de que mas debería hacer, espero me puedan ayudar, si necesitan algún tipo de código o tienen alguna duda no duden en pedirlo de antemano muchas gracias!!!

Comment: decir no funciona como que, no ayuda mucho ... como te podemos ayudar????

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent mas que todo busco una razón por la cual el desarrollo si me funciona pero en producción no, no tengo código que agregar mas que el que adjunto en en enlace de la pregunta,  tampoco un amplio conocimiento sobre el tema por eso no se si hay algo que estoy haciendo mal o dejando en el camino!!

Comment: la razon de esto : **desarrollo si me funciona pero en producción no** es muy difícil de debuggear si no se cuenta con un [mre]

Comment: es como llegar y preguntar: ***que numero sumados dan 20***.

Comment: hay muchos escenarios en los que Firebase Push Notifications puede no llegar a funciona en producción y en desarrollo si...

Comment: te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent gracias lo voy a tomar en cuenta voy a buscar la forma de mejorar la pregunta y la voy a actualizar!

Comment: Si no funciona ahora pueden permisos para la API, restricciòn, etc, pero debes agregar más información a tus preguntas revisa [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debe agregar Release sha-1 de Google Play a Firebase. Puede encontrar el sha-1 en la página web de Play Store en Setup -> App Integrity. Agregue el sha-1 a su proyecto de Firebase en Project Overview -> Settings. Luego, descargue el nuevo google-service.json de Firebase y agréguelo a su proyecto. Luego, reconstruya su aplicación y cárguela en Google Play. Las notificaciones deberían funcionar en esta nueva versión.

Comment: Hola Scott gracias por tu respuesta comentarte que como lo mencionaba aquí **lo mejor que he encontrado es que debo agregar las claves sha-1 y sha-256 pero esta vez de la Google Play Console en el apartado "integridad de la app" sin embargo no me ha funcionado** ya lo habia hecho pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Solo se necesita sha-1. No importa si agrega sha-256. ¿Agregó el nuevo google-services.json al app, reconstruyó la app y la cargó en Google Play, y todavía no funciona? Si el código funciona en debug pero no en release, debería ser que el problema sea sha-1. No conozco ninguna otra razón.

Comment: Si la verdad ya he hecho eso incluso he tratado de poner el token en un toast tambien he tratado de mandar el mensaje de forma directa pero es como si el codigo de firebase no sea reconocido la verdad he tratado muchisimas cosas pero nada parece funcionar, gracias de todas formas!!

Comment: Mi única otra idea es ejecutar un Signing Report en Android Studio y agregar este release sha-1 a Firebase también, si es diferente a la de Google Play sha-1.

Comment: Eso también lo hice, el problema es que no tengo nada que me diga que es lo que ocasiona el problema, por ejemplo este código lo utilizo para obtener el token del dispositivo: **FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(Login.this, instanceIdResult -> { token = instanceIdResult.getToken(); Log.i("FCM Token", token); Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "El token es "+token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }); y como ves tengo un toast pero ese toast no se muestra cuando abro la app desde google play es como si el código de firebase no se reconociera, la verdad no se.

Comment: Gracias por tu publicación, considera revisar [answer], saludos.