# Enviar mensajes personalizados consiguiendo algún identificador desde webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-messaging

resulta que tengo un webview al que quiero enviar mensajes personalizados a cada usuario (para esto tengo Firebase Cloud Messaging). En la web los usuarios se loguean por Google, lo que quiero es sacar algún identificador o algo que yo pueda enviar al backend para asociar una ID u algo y poder enviarle notificaciones personalizadas a un usuario concreto.

O obtener algún identificador único y que desde el backend yo pueda identificar que es ese usuario.

No se si se podría hacer...

Gracias de antemano.

EDIT:

Una vez tengo el método para hacer el post, si quiero pasar el token, de la siguiente forma me da error.

Variables declaradas:

```
Context cContext;
String token = "";
```

Cojo el token
token = task.getResult();

```
            // Log and toast
            String msg = "El token es el siguiente:" + token;
```

Método post
private void postMessage(String token) {

```
    RequestQueue myrequest= Volley.newRequestQueue(cContext);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    String url_foto="";

    try {
        json.put("to",token);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject notificacion=new JSONObject();
    try {
        notificacion.put("titulo", "Carrera cerca tuya");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        notificacion.put("detalle","¡No te la pierdas!'");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        notificacion.put("foto",url_foto);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        json.put("data",notificacion);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String URL="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null,null){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String,String>header=new HashMap<>();
            header.put("content-type","application/json");
            header.put("authorization","key=mi_key");

            return header;

        }
    };
    myrequest.add(request);
}
```

Si intento hacer postMessage(token) no compila...

Otra duda, si quiero enviar ese token a mi backend, podría poner otra url en el mismo postMessage o tendría que hacer otro método donde solo enviara el token

Comment: Para eso debes obtener el token del dispositivo, revisa una de mis preguntas donde envió una notificación utilizando el token de cada usuario quizá te sirva: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/495405/114296

Comment: @AdielMoran Definitivamente si que me sirve pero tengo varias dudas que voy a actualizar arriba.